# Issues and errors with Image Picker plugin for Flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I'm new to Dart and Flutter.

I'm trying to run the example code for ImagePicker from Pub.Dev (https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker). I'm starting with the example code provided in the ReadMe tab. I'm using image_picker: ^0.7.5+3 within the dependencies in pubspec.yaml

What I want to happen: in an IOS Simulator, when I select an image from the gallery, the selected image should show up in the body of the application. Using the example code from Pub.Dev ReadMe tab, the body shows the text: "No image selected." However, even if I select an image, the image is not shown, and the body text does not get replaced with the selected image.

Just by simply copy-pasting the example code from PubDev, I get two errors:

1. for File _image; => i get this error
   Error: Non-nullable instance field '_image' must be initialized.
   Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'.
   So, i tried to use instead: File? _image
2. However, the following error results in the line => : Image.file(_image),
   Error: The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.
   So I change the line to: : Image.file(_image!),

This removes the error, but the code doesn't seem to work (the selected image does not get shown in the body of the application).

Please help?

This is the full code I'm using with the modification I've outlined above:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );   } }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {   @override  
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(); }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {   File? _image;   final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Picker Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _image == null
            ? Text('No image selected.')
            : Image.file(_image!),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );   } }
```

**Other details:**

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: ^0.7.5+3
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

**Flutter Doctor results** (I'm using an IOS simulator, so I assume the issue with the Android toolchain has no impact?:

> [flutter] flutter doctor -v [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on
> macOS 11.3.1 20E241 darwin-arm, locale en-GB)
> • Flutter version 2.2.0 at /Users/JM/flutter
> • Framework revision b22742018b (13 days ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
> • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
> • Dart version 2.13.0
>
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.3)
> • Android SDK at /Users/JM/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
> ✗ Android license status unknown.
> Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
> See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
> more details.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
> • CocoaPods version 1.10.1
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
> • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
> • Flutter extension version 3.22.0
>
> [✓] Connected device (2 available)
> • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 1B078BE2-30D5-4972-A6DF-2748712A8641 • ios            •
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
> • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category. exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly with my android simulator.

I'm unfortunately not able to test for iOS currently as i have to renew my Macbook which is too old to get XCode 12.

Anyway, the Android license issue you have cannot have any impact for your refreshing screen issue, indeed.